# JavaFX bind not property member to control

Tags: java, binding, properties, javafx

Imagine I have a POJO like:

```
public class Person()
{
  private int id;
  private String name;

  public int getId()
  {
     return this.id;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
     return this.name;
  }
}
```

If I need to bind name member to JavaFX label using bind() method, I can't apply because I need and observable value.

I know that I can use StringProperty instead String, but I need primitive types because I use Hibernate and I don't know if Hibernate could support properties from JavaFX to map data from DB.

Which alternatives I have to bind from my pojo to a JavaFX control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

Firstly, it's possible to use FX Properties in JPA/Hibernate entities, though you have to be a little careful. In short, you need to make sure you use property access so that the ORM calls the get/set methods, instead of trying to set the field directly. Steven van Impe [discusses this on his blog](http://asipofjava.blogspot.com/2013/05/javafx-properties-in-jpa-entity-classes.html), and I also [blogged on the same topic](http://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2014/05/09/one-bean-to-bind-them-all/). One thing I haven't tried here is mapping collections and using `ObservableList`s: that might be tricky as JPA implementations use a subinterface of `List`.

Your other option is to make the properties "bound properties" in the Java Bean sense, and then to use a [Java Bean Property Adapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/adapter/package-summary.html):

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport ;

public class Person()
{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public int getId()
    {
       return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) 
    {
       int oldId = this.id ;
       this.id = id ;
       pcs.firePropertyChange("id", oldId, id);
    }

    public String getName()
    {
       return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        String oldName = this.name ;
        this.name = name ;
        pcs.firePropertyChange("name", oldName, name);
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
Label nameLabel = new Label();
Person person = new Person();
nameLabel.textProperty().bind(JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create()
    .bean(person)
    .name("name") // name of property to bind to
    .build());
```

Comment: It seems to work for me if I don't add PropertyChangeSupport to the to the Person bean - what is the value add for using PropertyChangeSupport?

Comment: `PropertyChangeSupport` just provides the mechanism for registering `PropertyChangeListener`s and firing `PropertyChangeEvent`s. AIUI, the adapter registers with the bean to listen for those events, if possible, so that it can update bound values if the property in the POJO changes.

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/james-d/a213d9b768e036e08b6f) an example of the difference. Without the `PropertyChangeSupport` (or at least an equivalent mechanism), notifications don't get sent.

Comment: That's so weird, without the PropertyChangeSupport, the bound value still gets updated, but change listeners don't fire, whereas, with PropertyChangeSupport, both the bound value gets updated and the change listeners fire.

Comment: I guess (it's a guess), if the adapter can't register a listener it takes a conservative approach and always assumes the current value might be invalid. So in that case, when you call `get` on the bound property, it's going to retrieve the value from the POJO. However, if you bind, say, the `textProperty()` of a label to a POJO with no `PropertyChangeSupport`, it won't know to repaint the label if the POJO changes (haven't tested it though).

Comment: You are right, without the PropertyChangeSupport, the label's bound text property value changes when you set the a new value on the POJO, but the label's displayed text on the screen does not change to reflect the new text property value - it is so strange.

Comment: Without the `PropertyChangeSuppport` it behaves the same way as a "naive" property implementation that omits to notify invalidation listeners when its value changes. This makes sense (to me): without the property change event it has no idea it needs to do that. When you `get` the value, it simply delegates to the underlying POJO method (which gives the "correct" result). There's no point in the adapter caching the value as the POJO, even with a property change mechanism, lacks an invalidation mechanism. (I suspect this last point is why they created JavaFX properties.) Updated gist...