# how to bind/ unbind a Date type attribute to a DatePicker object

Tags: jpa, binding, javafx, javabeans

i have the following code:

```
@FXML
private DatePicker birthday; 
//other code               
private final ChangeListener<Person> personListener = (value, oldValue, newValue) -> {
//other code
birthday.valueProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldValue.getBirthday());
//other code
};
```

birthday property is of type java.time.LocalDate, and belongs to a class Person. because I use JPA, I want do not to use JavaFX properties.
The above code fails to compile. The compiler's error message is:

```
error: no suitable method found for unbindBidirectional(LocalDate)
       birthDayPicker.valueProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldV.getBirthday());
method Property.unbindBidirectional(Property<LocalDate>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; LocalDate cannot be converted to Property<LocalDate>)
method ObjectProperty.unbindBidirectional(Property<LocalDate>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; LocalDate cannot be converted to Property<LocalDate>)
```

How can i solve this problem?

**Update:**
My person class has the followin code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByFirstname", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.firstname = :firstname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByLastname", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.lastname = :lastname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByMail", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.mail = :mail"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByBirthday", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.birthday = :birthday")})
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name = "MAIL")
    private String mail;
    @Column(name = "BIRTHDAY")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate birthday;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Person(Integer id, String firstname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        Integer oldId = this.id;
        this.id = id;
         listenerList.firePropertyChange("id", oldId, id);
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        String oldFirstName = this.firstname;
        this.firstname = firstname;
         listenerList.firePropertyChange("firstname", oldFirstName, firstname);
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        String oldLastName = this.lastname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
          listenerList.firePropertyChange("mail", oldLastName, lastname);
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        String oldMail = this.mail;
        this.mail = mail;
        listenerList.firePropertyChange("mail", oldMail, mail);
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
        LocalDate oldBirthDay = this.birthday;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        listenerList.firePropertyChange("birthday", id, birthday);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Person)) {
            return false;
        }
        Person other = (Person) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "jpa.entities.Person[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

    @Transient
    final private PropertyChangeSupport listenerList = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        listenerList.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);

    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        listenerList.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);

    }

}
```

the controller class:

```
public class PersonController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TableView<Person> personsTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, Integer> idColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> firstColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> lastColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, LocalDate> birthdayColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> mailColumn;
@FXML
private TextField id;
@FXML
private TextField firstName;
@FXML
private TextField lastName;
@FXML
private TextField mail;
@FXML
private DatePicker birthDayPicker;
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
private EntityManager em;
private ObservableList<Person> data;
private LocalDate birthday;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceTest");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    birthDayPicker.setOnAction((ActionEvent evnt) -> {
        birthday = birthDayPicker.getValue();

    });
    personsTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(personListener);
    configureColumn();
    populate();
}

@FXML
private void addPerson(ActionEvent event) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Person p = new Person(Integer.parseInt(id.getText()), firstName.getText());
    p.setLastname(lastName.getText());
    p.setBirthday(birthDayPicker.getValue());
    p.setMail(mail.getText());
    em.persist(p);
    data.add(p);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}

@FXML
private void savePerson(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
private void deletePerson(ActionEvent event) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Person p = personsTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().getValue();
    data.remove(p);
    em.remove(p);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}

private void populate() {
    TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT e FROM Person e", jpa.entities.Person.class);
    List<Person> list = query.getResultList();
    data.addAll(list);
    personsTable.setItems(data);
}

private void configureColumn() {
    idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Integer>("id"));
    firstColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstname"));
    lastColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastname"));
    birthdayColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, LocalDate>("birthday"));
    birthdayColumn.setCellFactory(p -> {
        return new TableCell<Person, LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    final DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    setText(item.format(format));

                }
            }
        };
    });
    mailColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("mail"));

}

private final ChangeListener<Person> personListener = (value, oldV, newV) -> {
    if (oldV != null) {
        id.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldV.getId());
        firstName.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldV.getFirstname());
        lastName.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldV.getLastname());
        birthDayPicker.valueProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldV.getBirthday()); // error
        mail.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldV.getMail());

    }
    if (newV != null) {
        try {
            id.textProperty().bindBidirectional(JavaBeanIntegerPropertyBuilder.create().bean(newV).name("id").build(), new NumberStringConverter());
            firstName.textProperty().bindBidirectional(JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create().bean(newV).name("firstname").build());
            lastName.textProperty().bindBidirectional(JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create().bean(newV).name("lastname").build());
            birthDayPicker.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(); // error
            mail.textProperty().bindBidirectional(JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create().bean(newV).name("mail").build());

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("erreur : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

};

}
```

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959392/javafx-bind-not-property-member-to-control/ helps. You should at least use a `java.time.LocalDate`, even if you don't want to use JavaFX properties (using properties, which you can do with JPA, will make your life easier).

Comment: @ James_D That doesn't really help me. i changed the type to LocalDate.  JPA recognize it (i added a class that  implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date>). what is next?

Comment: Either use JavaFX properties and bind to the `ObjectProperty<LocalDate>`, or add `PropertyChangeSupport` and bind to a `JavaBeanPropertyAdapter`, as in the linked question.

Comment: @James_D see the update, the problem persists

Comment: Again, you have to bind to a JavaBeanPropertyAdapter if you are not going to use JavaFX properties. I will post an answer when I am back at a computer.

Comment: thanks very much.  for binding, i used: birthDayPicker.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder.create().bean(newV).name("birthday").build()); it works. but How about unbinding. i must use the method unbind with no argument?

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the adapter. See posted answer. I still think it's better to use JavaFX properties in the entity class, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is simply to use JavaFX properties in your `Person` class. This works with JPA as long as you use "property access" instead of "field access". I.e.:

```
public class Person {

    private final StringProperty firstname = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty firstnameProperty() {
        return firstname ;
    }

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    public final String getFirstname() {
        return firstnameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        firstnameProperty().set(firstname);
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthday = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthdayProperty() {
        return birthday ;
    }

    @Column(name="BIRTHDAY")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthdayProperty().get();
    }
    public void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
        birthdayProperty().set(birthday);
    }

    // etc 
}
```

(Note that Hibernate still objects to `final` `get` and `set` methods, so you would have to make those methods non-final if you use Hibernate, which is slightly less than ideal. If you use a JPA-compliant ORM this shouldn't cause a problem.)

If you cannot use JavaFX properties in your entity for some reason, you can manage the binding with a `JavaBeanObjectProperty`. Code along the following lines should work:

```
public class PersonController {

    private JavaBeanObjectProperty birthdayPropertyAdapter ;

    // ...

private final ChangeListener<Person> personListener = (value, oldV, newV) -> {
    if (oldV != null) {
        id.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldV.getId());
        firstName.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldV.getFirstname());
        lastName.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldV.getLastname());
        mail.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldV.getMail());

    }

    if (birthdayPropertyAdapter != null) {
            birthdayPicker.valueProperty().unbindBidirectional(birthdayPropertyAdapter);
    }

    if (newV != null) {
        try {
            id.textProperty().bindBidirectional(JavaBeanIntegerPropertyBuilder.create().bean(newV).name("id").build(), new NumberStringConverter());
            firstName.textProperty().bindBidirectional(JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create().bean(newV).name("firstname").build());
            lastName.textProperty().bindBidirectional(JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create().bean(newV).name("lastname").build());
            mail.textProperty().bindBidirectional(JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create().bean(newV).name("mail").build());

    birthdayPropertyAdapter = JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder.create()
    .bean(newV)
    .name("birthday")
    .build();

    birthdayPicker.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(birthdayPropertyAdapter);

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("erreur : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the type of date in your Person class, then add and use appropriate accessors.

```
public class Person {
    final private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthday;

    public Person(LocalDate birthday) {
        this.birthday = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(birthday);
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthday.get();
    }

    public void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
        this.birthday.set(birthday);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthdayProperty() {
        return birthday;
    }
}

. . .

@FXML
private DatePicker birthday; 
//other code               
private final ChangeListener<Person> personListener = (value, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    //other code
    birthday.valueProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldValue.birthdayProperty());
    //other code
};
```

Comment: i want do not to use javafx properties. I use JPA.

Comment: Adding constraints like this to your question is always a good idea.